# Facebook app API key and UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, facebook, uiactivityviewcontroller

Is it possible to supply a Facebook API Key when posting to Facebook from a UIActivityViewController?

If not, then how would it be possible to add the Facebook SDK to be used with the UIActivityViewController?

I basically want to use the share sheet to make a facebook post, but want it to have Deep Linking with my app.

Possible?

Comment: Guys! Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is possible but you might look into OvershareKit https://github.com/overshare/overshare-kit

It allows for sharing on many different mediums but it also handles the Facebook API sharing using a Facebook API key instead of using the UIActivityViewController built-in methods.